# Show $x^{1-\epsilon}= O(\pi(x))$ for $\epsilon >0.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm following a proof of the Prime Number Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) and in it I believe we require the following inequality:

$$x^{1-\epsilon}= O(\pi(x))\text{  for  }\epsilon >0.$$

How can I show this to be true without using the theorem I am trying to prove?

Comment: Chebyshev already proved $\pi(x) \asymp \frac{x}{\log x}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If this proof needs the theorem result to prove it, then surely it is not a correct proof?

Comment: But it doesn't. Chebyshev's result is that there are $0 < a < b$ and $x_0$ such that $$a\frac{x}{\log x} \leqslant \pi(x) \leqslant b\frac{x}{\log x}$$ for $x \geqslant x_0$. That's less than $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ (and was proved nearly 50 years before the latter).

Comment: @DanielFischer I apologise; I misread your earlier comment. I understand now, thank you.

Comment: Which step specifically in the proof sketch do you think requires it?

Comment: @user361424 I think we need this for showing $\psi(x) \sim\pi (x) \log x$, in particular the part where we put a lower bound on the $\psi$ function.

Comment: @user361424 I think I understand this. For my own clarification, is this passage on inequalities with the aim of showing $\psi (x) \sim \pi (x)\log x$?